# i18next-scanner implementation challenges

Tags: reactjs, react-i18next

I have started using react-i18next recently in my react application. I am able to use resource files in the directory to translate strings. But creating resource files with help of i18next-scanner became a challenge as there is no end to end implementation guide for this. I have followed the official documentation. I feel that I am still missing something in implementation. The below CLI command is giving error.

command: i18next-scanner --config src/i18next-scanner.config.js 'src/**/*.{js,jsx}'
error: i18next-scanner is not recognized as an internal or external command.

Where do i need to use the standard API in my code?

Answer (score 2):

Run `npx i18next-scanner` on the commandline